# Having 2 <head> in 1 page

Tags: html, meta, head

I have 2 `<head>` tags in one web page. Reason is that I used to have the header, the content and the footer views loaded separately, so I left 1 `<head>` in the header view and another in the content view.

What's the effect of this? If it's not compliant with html standard, then should I get rid of all extra `<head>` and only leave 1 in 1 page?

Comment: I was really asking to see if this writing code like this is acceptable to html standards. SEO is an off-topic discussion.

Comment: Okay, then could you try to rephrase the question a bit? (e.g., remove the question "What's the effect of this, in terms of SEO?" as well as the [tag:seo] tag, and add whatever your actual question may be)

Answer (score 1):

This is what HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><!-- The *required* head -->
        <title>The *required* title</title>
    </head>
    <body><!-- The *required* body -->
        Stuff
    </body>
</html>
```

Don't do anything besides that - that includes using two head tags. I think what you want is iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's specifically what happens, when an HTML5-compliant browser parses a document with two `head` elements:

- gets to the first `</head>` tag: [The "after head" insertion mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-after-head-insertion-mode)
- encounters the second `<head>` tag: "Parse error. Ignore the token."
- encounters some other tags, e.g. `<meta>`: Parse error, but it basically adds the tag to the previous `head` element.
- encounters second `</head>` tag: "Parse error. Ignore the token."

So what does this mean? **It is a parse error** to have multiple `head`s. However, the standard is clear on what should happen in this case. It does the "right" thing and merges the them.

I should also point out that `<head></head>` tags are optional. You can leave them out and have no parse errors.

Comment: So does it mean that I can simply write <meta> tags without using the <head></head>? Thanks!